# Is it possible to solve $\dfrac{x}{\tan x}$?

Tags: trigonometry

I have the equation $\dfrac{x}{\tan x} = y $ which I would like to rearrange so that I can express $x$ in terms of $y$. Are there any trigonometric identities that can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This class of equations which mix polynomial and trigonometric terms do not show, at least in general, analytical solution and numerical methods should be used. The simplest could be probably Newton which, starting at a "reasonable" guess $x_0$, will update it according to $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$ In the present case $$f(x)=\frac{x}{\tan(x)}-y$$ $$f'(x)=\cot (x)-x \csc ^2(x)$$ The problem is to find the starting point; fortunately, for $0\leq x\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$, it is quite easy to build the approximation $$\frac{x}{\tan(x)}\approx \frac{1-\frac{2 x^2}{5}}{1-\frac{x^2}{15}}$$ which means that, for $0\leq y\leq 1$, the estimate of the first root will be $$x_0=\pm\sqrt{\frac{15 (1-y)}{6-y}}$$

Comment: Thanks Claude, I had a feeling a numeric method would be needed.

Comment: @keith. You are very welcome ! The nice thing is that, in a given interval, we can build nice approximations of the function will allow to generate a quite good estimate of the solution and then, let Newton do the job ! Cheers :-)

Comment: @keith. I suppose that, for a better stability, knowing an estimate of the solution, I should solve $x\,\cos(x)-y\,\sin(x)=0$

Comment: Many thanks, $ xcos(x)−ysin(x)=0 $ tends to an answer very quickly compared to $ \frac{x}{tan(x)} - y $

Comment: @keith. When possible, it is always better to remove singularities, asymptotes,... Cheers